# .Net Web api slow on server but fine locally

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

Angular SPA, Deploying a Web api application to IIS 10 windows 2016 server.  Locally the api runs fine around a second per data call.  When deployed, it gets extremely slow almost a minute or two per call.  I cannot figure out what is happening.

- When first deployed the api runs fine for about a minute, then starts slowing down. I know this because I've created an entirely different solution with the same code around 3 times and each time it's the same thing, runs fine then slows.
- Calls from the application are slow, but it is also slow accessing the api via browser.  This seems to me that this is strictly an api issue.  Other functionality in the Angular app run fine.

Any help is obviously appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this level of info.  One obvious place to check when an app starts slowing down is if you have a memory leak somewhere.  It may not be as obvious in dev if you have a high-powered local workstation that's only running your app (it will slow down slower).  Reviewing logs and metrics on the production server would be the first place to start (look at mem usage, disk IO, etc).

Comment: I've monitored the web server when accessing the API.  Nothing of note.  No spikes in memory or disk usage.  I have run the Chrome performance monitor and the biggest lag is with "Layout".  Not sure what is going on there, unless it is something to do with rendering the JSON?

Comment: how much time it will take to load the content? what is the size of the content? you could try to enable enableProdMode() in both the boot-client.ts and boot-server.ts. please refer this git issue link:https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/292

Comment: I don't think, pretty certain, that the issue is not the angular app.  I run the API directly through FireFox/Chrome/IE, absent of the Angular front end, and the API is still very slow.

Comment: how much time it will take to load the content? you could share the snapshot of the browser network tab.